# LaTeX error when drawing circuits with Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am currently running the following document from [this Qiskit documentation](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/aqua/general/amplitude_estimation.ipynb).

This notebook is running in Jupyter, and I started Jupyter from the Mac terminal within a Conda environment. Normally, this works fine with Qiskit. The problem is that when I run the command:

`ae._circuit.draw(output='latex')`

I get the following error:

`WARNING: Unable to compile latex. Is 'pdflatex' installed? Skipping latex circuit drawing...`

I tried `conda install pdflatex` and many variations of this, but nothing worked so far. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the pdflatex binary. Install pdflatex from your OS's LaTeX installer. For MacOS, follow this link: [Where do I get the pdflatex program for Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/1038612/where-do-i-get-the-pdflatex-program-for-mac).